# UITextFieldView markedTextRange crash on iOS4?

Tags: ios

My apps use UITextFieldView to receive input method from user and work fine on iOS6/iOS7. and I am using the following code to prevent user input chinese/japanese/something like that. Method to detect the real input words:

```
-(void)textFieldChanged:(UITextField *)textField 

//crash here if device iOS version at 4.3

UITextRange *selectRange = [textField markedTextRange];

if (selectRange == nil)
//get word to do something...
```

Crash log :

```
 2013-11-20 12:35:09.480 [My app][203:607]-[UITextField markedTextRange]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x287e270

2013-11-20 12:35:09.480 [My app][203:607] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextField markedTextRange]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x287e270'
```

Comment: I'm curios, why are you trying to do this in iOS 4?

Comment: I guess arround 98% people using iOS7 and remaining are using iOS6 then why are you trying it for iOS4?

Comment: I'd bet that function isn't available on iOS 4.

Comment: `markedTextRange` is a member in the `UITextInput` protocol (with `UITextField` conforms to) since iOS 3.2 according to the official documentation.

Comment: @uranusjr The docs do seem to indicate this should work but the runtime error indicates otherwise.

Comment: looks like iOS4 system issue. Now i have tried on iOS5 and work fine.